# Resque Workers on Heroku locked out of Postgres DB SSL- no fix yet

Tags: postgresql, heroku, redis, actionmailer, resque

I'm using resque/redis on heroku to send emails as a background job. It works fine for the first email I send, but after that I get the error: (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac :) ...

I've seen the other questions/answers that say to add to an initializer:

Resque.after_fork = Proc.new { ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection }
OR

Resque.before_fork = Proc.new { ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection }

However, I have done this (and tried any other thing I can think of) and I'm still getting the same error. I have run the code with only before_fork and only after_fork to no avail.

I am also using APN_sender to send apple push notifications. The workers for these have had no problems (but I'm calling default Heroku workers to do these rather than Resque workers).

Here are my relevant files, please help! This is my first SO question as well.. apologies if it's not done perfectly.

```
#config/resque.rb
after_fork do |server, worker, resque|
   logger.info("Got to after_fork in resque.rb config file")
defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
   ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end

--------------------

#config/initializers/resque.rb
require 'resque'
require 'resque/server'

heroku_environments = ["staging", "production"]
rails_root = ENV['RAILS_ROOT'] || File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../..'
rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development'

#confusing wording..  determines whether or not we are in Production, tested and working
unless heroku_environments.include?(rails_env)
   resque_config = YAML.load_file(rails_root + '/config/resque.yml')
   Resque.redis = resque_config[rails_env]
else
   uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] || "redis://localhost:6379/")
   Resque.redis = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
end

----------------------

#resque.rake
require 'resque/tasks'

task "resque:setup" => :environment do
  ENV['QUEUE'] = '*'
  Resque.after_fork = Proc.new { ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection }
  Resque.before_fork = Proc.new { ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection }
end

task "apn:setup" => :environment do
  ENV['QUEUE'] = '*'
end

desc "Alias for resque:work (To run workers on Heroku)"
task "jobs:work" => "resque:work"

desc "Alias for apn:work (To run workers on Heroku)"
task "jobs:work" => "apn:work"

-----------------------

#Sending the email
@event.guests.each do |g|
    Resque.enqueue(MailerCallback, "Notifier", :time_change, @event.id, g.id)
end
```

I am running one Heroku worker and one Resque worker from the Heroku ps:scale command. As I said, the first email sends error-free, and then any emails after get the above error.

Thanks in advance!
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so couldn't figure this out...

Switched over to delayed job and it's working much better. A little frustrating that I can't send push notifications with apn_sender anymore, but apn_on_rails is working fine.

Weird problem, still curious...

Comment: I read that Resque doesn't work well with Postgres. I think I will try Delayed Job or Queue Classic instead.